# No transform is available between OGC:CRS84 - WGS 84 (CRS84) and EPSG:3035 - ETRS89-extended / LAEA Europe

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, shapefile, error, windows-10

I am trying to add a shapefile to QGIS that contains reconstructed UK postcode polygons (January 2015), which can be found in this link https://www.opendoorlogistics.com/downloads/ in the section 'UK postcode boundary polygons'. The file I use is named 'Districts.shp' and it worked fine when I had the Windows QGIS version downloaded via the Standalone installer via this link https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html.

However, I was having issues with GRASS (I needed to use the r.reclass function) and I therefore found out that I needed to download QGIS via the OSGeo4W Network Installer to solve the error I was getting. Now that GRASS is working, though, I am having this error that I didn't have before when adding the shapefile 'Districts.shp'.

This error says *'No transform is available between OGC:CRS84 - WGS 84 (CRS84) and EPSG:3035 - ETRS89-extended / LAEA Europe'*, and the problem I am having with this is that I don't see the postcode division that I would usually see when adding this layer. It is also worth mentioning that this issue is also not happening to a colleague of mine who is using a Mac version. He is not having the issue with GRASS or this one with adding this same exact shapefile into QGIS. Let me know if I can add more details so you can help me with this!

[image: Here you can see the error that pops up every time I add the layer]

Comment: Possibly related ~ https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ticket/616  you may need to download the proj-datumgrid-europe ~ https://github.com/OSGeo/proj-datumgrid/releases/tag/europe-1.6